# Azure Search remove data that is not in data-source

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a file in blob storage `folder/new/data.json`

It contains json array.

```
[   
    {
        "name": "a",
        "data": {
            "1":"something1",
            "2":"something2"

        }
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "data": {
            "1":"something1",
            "2":"something2"
        }
    }
]
```

my datasource body :

```
{
    "name" : "datasource",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "MyStorageConnStrning" },
    "container" : { "name" : "mycontaner", "query" : "folder/new" }
}
```

my index body:

```
{
    "name" : "index",
    "fields": [
       { "name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false },
       { "name": "name", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": true},
       { "name": "data", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false}
    ]
}
```

indexer body:

```
{
    "name" : "indexer",
    "dataSourceName" : "datasource",
    "targetIndexName" : "index",
    "parameters" : { "configuration" : { "parsingMode" : "jsonArray" } }
}
```

when created i can search for `a` and `b` and get result.

now i have modified `folder/new/data.json` to

```
[   
    {
        "name": "aa",
        "data": {
            "1":"something1",
            "2":"something2"

        }
    }
]
```

just running the indexer only overwrites

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "data": {
       "1":"something1",
       "2":"something2"

    }
}
```

but

```
{
    "name": "b",
    "data": {
        "1":"something1",
        "2":"something2"
    }
}
```

still remains. Meaning `b` is still searchable.

What can i do so the `b` gets removed?

More preciously What to do when data-source file is changed and index data need to change accordingly? Removed data from the data-source needs to get removed from index and new data in data-source needs get indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nafis,

You should look into adding a [soft delete policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-deletion-detection-policies). Just removing the data from the data source doesn't mean existing records are deleted. If you added an "IsDeleted" field to the json object, set it to true, and ran your indexer again then the record would be deleted

```
[   
    {
    "name": "a",
    "data": {
        "1":"something1",
        "2":"something2"
       }
    },
    {
    "name": "b",
    "data": {
        "1":"something1",
        "2":"something2"
      },
    "isDeleted": true
    }
]
```

Once your indexer has run again, you can then safely remove the "b" object from your json array. I recommend making sure your indexer [is on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer#indexer-schedule) so deletes are automatically picked up after a period of time.

Please let me know if you have additional questions.

Matt

Comment: If i delete the index, recreate it and run the indexer will it also work?

Comment: Yes, the indexer will index all the data in the array again